# ERROR has exited with code 3221226356 (0xc0000374) usando funciones de un SDK

Tags: c#, windows-forms, sdk, out-of-memory-error

Estoy trabajando en proyecto win Forms donde me conecto a un sistema contable "Adminpaq" usando su SDK. En estos momentos me encuentro trabajando en la impresion de documentos a la cual tego que usar las funciones del SDK para acceder a la info de las bases de datos por esto no hay problema, ya que he podido acceder a la info, pero para el caso de las facturas se requiere obtener datos de CFDi el sdk tiene una funcion para ello es fObtieneDatosCFDi(string password); cuando la ejecuto es cuando obtengo has exited with code 3221226356 (0xc0000374)

tengo una app de consola  de ejemplo que solo obtiene datos CFDI y digamos que funciona hasta un determinado mometo por que despue arroja el mismo error. Mi app tabien funciona y trae datos una o dos veces antes de comemzar a arrojar el error. Esta es la app de consola.

este es un fragmento de la app aqui intento llamar algun dato y cargarlo en algun label a modo prueba

```
rutaLabel.Text = _ruta;
oSdk.startSDK();
AdminpaqSDK.EmpresasAdminpaqSDK.fAbreEmpresa(_ruta);
DisplayConcepts();
List<Empresas> empresa = oSdk.GetEmpresasData(_ruta);
dataGridView1.DataSource = empresa;
AdminpaqSDK.DocumentosAdminpaqSDK.fBuscarIdDocumento(2);
StringBuilder test = new StringBuilder(500);
        ///////////////
int d AdminpaqSDK.DocumentosAdminpaqSDK.fObtieneDatosCFDI("");
AdminpaqSDK.DocumentosAdminpaqSDK.fLeeDatoCFDI(test, 4);
label2.Text = test.ToString();
```

Comment: Lamentablemente tu problema es irreproducible. Lo que yo he visto en otro casos no relacionados, es que es muy típico que las consultas se dividen en 2 o más. Un primera consulta para traer cierto tipos de datos, lo cuales te sirven como parámetros para la segunda consulta

Comment: si, todo iba ien hasta que me tope con este problema